# $.filedownload in javascript gives '$ is not defined'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am very new to jquery and js but have this code in myphp.php file:

```
<?php
echo "<div><tr><a href='javascript:getspreadsheets();'>Cape Culture (10 years)</a></tr><br />";
echo "<tr><a href='javascript:getspreadsheets();'>Winsters (5 Years)</a></tr><br />";
echo "<tr><a href='javascript:getspreadsheets();'>Kayo (1 year)</a></tr><br />";
echo "<tr><a href='javascript:getspreadsheets(1498);'>Col Timbers</a></tr></div>";
?>

  <script type="text/javascript">
function getspreadsheets(val)
{
    alert(val);
    var self = this,

        activityguid = self.activityguid,
        accountguid  = self.accountguid

        $.fileDownload(
            'data/export.items_to_csv.php',
            {
                httpMethod: 'POST',
                data: {
                    activityguid : activityguid,
                    accountguid  : accountguid,
                    classid      : val
                }
            });
        alert(val);
    //}
}
 </script>
```

when i run it i get the first alert but then get an error stating the $ is undefined?
can some one help please?
thanks

Comment: Are you linking to a jquery script?

Comment: Did you include jQuery?

Comment: Did you include a jQuery script? Here's one from the Google CDN: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: let me add my other code

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your include for jQuery is before this script section, and that you are actually including jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like either you are not including jQuery or you're including it after your script. Make sure the jQuery script tag is *before* your application script.

Comment: since scripts load synchronously, the statement about jQuery not being loaded in time seems to be invalid in the provided context

Comment: Actually it's better to have all of your scripts at the end of your document right before `</body>`. Also, jQuery will always load in time because scripts load synchronously. The only way there would be a problem is if the script loads asynchronously because of an `async` attribute in the `<script></script>` tag. No `async`, no problem.

Comment: That's very true actually. Bit of a dunce moment on my part haha.

Comment: Edited the original answer

Answer (score 0):

Add this code

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
```